# List of nfs mounted filesystems in AIX

Tags: nfs, aix

I wanted to get the list of nfs mounted filesystems from some file present in the AIX machine. Is it present in some file? Currently, the only way that I know, is using mount system call and then parsing the output accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In AIX to get the NFS mounted filesystems you can use command like:

```
df -T remote
```

or command `mount`

```
mount|grep -i nfs
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `-T remote`, [as Romeo mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509176/117549), you can tell [`df`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/df.htm) to look for certain filesystem types (vfstype):

```
{ df -T nfs; df -T nfs3; df -T nfs4; }
```

... where I picked out the unique, supported NFS types from `/etc/vfs` with something like `awk '$1 ~ /nfs/' /etc/vfs`. Note that `nfs3` is the same vfs_number as `nfsv3`, so pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

`df -Th | grep nfs` should do the job (`-T` to show the type / `-h` human readable).

Also under any Unix, there's a `/etc/mtab` which contains the currently mounted FS.
It's the pending of `/etc/fstab` with the difference that's dynamic so include also the manually mounted FS.

Comment: There is no /etc/mtab or /etc/fstab file

Comment: `df -Th` is an error on AIX: "df: not a filterable  VFS type"; also note that grepping for `nfs` could result in a false-positive on filesystems that happened to have "nfs" in their name somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to list NFS filesystems that are contained in `/etc/filesystems` then you can use the [lsnfsmnt command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/lsnfsmnt.htm) but for manually-mounted NFS filesystems you would have to resort to parsing the output from df or mount, as mentioned in the previous answers.